# How to create a dynamic list, which removes deleted items from an array in JS?

Tags: javascript, list, dynamic-arrays

I have created a list, which creates a new paragraph, with the value of the input field and adds the value of the input field into an array, if the add-Button is pressed. Each paragraph has a delete Button, which removes the paragraph visually, if pressed. Now I want that the Input of the paragraph also gets removed from the array.

For example lets say, that the array usernames includes usernames[1] = Lukas, usernames[2] = Martin, usernames[3] = Bob and I want to delete the paragraph, which includes Martin.
How can I create a function, where the paragraphs content also automatically gets removed from the array usernames. I would be very thankful for some help.
Here is my code:

```
let name = document.getElementById('name');
let addButton = document.getElementById('button');
let output = document.getElementById('output')

let usernames = [];

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    usernames.push(document.getElementById('name').value)
    console.log(usernames)

let paragraph = document.createElement('ul')
    paragraph.innerText = document.getElementById('name').value
    output.appendChild(paragraph)

let deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "X"
    paragraph.appendChild(deleteButton)

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        output.removeChild(paragraph)
    })
})
```

Comment: You could apply a user-name attribute to the HTML and when the button is clicked check it and remove that user-name. Now in cases where there could duplicates give each entered user a unique ID or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, but unfortunately the inner Text of the delete Button gets added to the array content, if something gets deleted, because it is part of the 'li' component. I simply created a div which includes the name and the delete Button to solve the problem. But nevertheless thank you for your help. Thats the working code:

```js
const user = document.getElementById('user');
const add = document.querySelector('.add');
const list = document.querySelector('.list')

let usernames = [];

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let name = user.value;
  user.value = '';
  usernames.push(name);
  console.log(usernames);

  const paragraph = document.createElement('div')
  paragraph.style.display = 'flex'

  const item = document.createElement('li');

  item.textContent = name + '  ';
  list.append(paragraph);
  paragraph.append(item)

  const del = document.createElement('button');

  del.textContent = "X";

  paragraph.append(del);

  del.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.closest('div').remove();

    usernames = [...list.querySelectorAll('li')].map(item => item.textContent);

    console.log(usernames);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find an element in the array by name and remove it from there:

```
const usernameToRemove = usernames.indexOf(name => name === paragraph.innerText);
usernames.splice(usernameToRemove, 1);
```

```js
let name = document.getElementById('name');
let addButton = document.getElementById('button');
let output = document.getElementById('output')

let usernames = [];

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    usernames.push(document.getElementById('name').value)
    console.log(usernames)

let paragraph = document.createElement('ul')
    paragraph.innerText = document.getElementById('name').value
    output.appendChild(paragraph)

let deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
    deleteButton.innerHTML = "X"
    paragraph.appendChild(deleteButton)

    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const usernameToRemove = usernames.indexOf(name => name === paragraph.innerText);
        usernames.splice(usernameToRemove, 1);
        output.removeChild(paragraph)
    })
})
```

```html
<input id="name">
<button id="button">button</button>
<div id="output">output</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time the event handler to delete an item is called, just collect all of the text of each item and convert it into an array.

```js
  del.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.closest('li').remove();
    usernames = [...list.querySelectorAll('li')].map(item => item.textContent);
    console.log(usernames);
  });
  /*
  This removes an <li>, if you don't change your "paragraph" then
  change 'li' to 'ul'
  */
```

```js
const user = document.getElementById('user');
const add = document.querySelector('.add');
const list = document.querySelector('.list')

let usernames = [];

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let name = user.value;
  user.value = '';
  usernames.push(name);
  console.log(usernames);
  const item = document.createElement('li');
  item.textContent = name+' ';
  list.append(item);
  const del = document.createElement('button');
  del.textContent = "X";
  item.append(del);
  del.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.closest('li').remove();
    usernames = [...list.querySelectorAll('li')].map(item => item.textContent);
    console.log(usernames);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id='user'><button class='add'>ADD</button>
<ul class='list'></ul>
```